# how to iterate arraylist five times but not the same numbers?

Tags: java, loops, random

I try to simulate a powerball numbers pick up program.
I can get random numbers in range but how to make it random 5 times?
looks the for loop only print result 5 times but won't go random loop once again.
here is the code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class lottery {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> whiteBalls = new ArrayList<>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        Random randi = new Random();
        //non duplicate numbers 1-69
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            while(true){
                int whiteBall = rand.nextInt(69)+1;
                if(!whiteBalls.contains(whiteBall)){
                    whiteBalls.add(whiteBall);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        int redBall = randi.nextInt(26)+1;  //special 1-26
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        System.out.println(whiteBalls + " " + redBall);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing your results at the end 5 times. Instead of once for each element in the list. The ArrayList has a built-in toString() method that can let you print it. To fix your problem, however, you need to run your same code 5 times over instead of just printing the list 5 times as each time you print it it's still the same as the last time and has not been regenerated with 5 new values. You can simplify this task by wrapping your code in a function then simply calling that function 5 times through a for loop. Check out the code I pasted below and see if that's what you were looking for.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class lottery {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random randi = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int redBall = randi.nextInt(26)+1;  //special 1-26
            System.out.println("Whiteball: " + generateWhiteBalls());
            System.out.println("Redball: " + redBall);
        }
    }
    
    public static List<Integer> generateWhiteBalls()
    {
        List<Integer> whiteBalls = new ArrayList<>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        //non duplicate numbers 1-69
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            while(true){
                int whiteBall = rand.nextInt(69)+1;
                if(!whiteBalls.contains(whiteBall)){
                    whiteBalls.add(whiteBall);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return whiteBalls;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked~!I will try to use some methods and calling outside of main but current it worked. thank you